# JavaScript array not filtering duplicate items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

my array filter does not work and I not sure which part was wrong. My sample data:

```
var arr = [
    {accountID: '-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8', age: 31, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'},
    {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female}
];
```

I wanted to filter out the same accountID. I found this solution online:

```
arr = arr.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
   return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
});
```

When I tried to print out the filtered array using this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(arr[i][0].accountID + ' ' + arr[i][0].age + ' ' + arr[i][0].gender);
}
```

I get back the exact same array with duplicate results. Which part was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are the objects inside `arr` the same objects (literally the same, not structurally the same) as `inputArray`?

Comment: It seems to me that your filter function doesn't actually do anything.  The callback is called once per element of the original array; for each element, it also passes in the index of that element.  The index of the element will always equal itself, so I would expect every item is returned by the filter.

Comment: @MinusFour Sorry but I thought the inputArray is just a parameter of the function? In this case, it is arr right?

Comment: @Amy Yeah it printed out the exact same array at the for loop that part

Comment: What is you condition that those elements are equal? That the `accountID` is the same or that all three fields are the same. You cannot find duplicates using `inputArray.indexOf(item) == index`  because each of the objects you have in the array is an unique object, even if they have the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES2015, you can use **[`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** to store unique values of any type.

The following example loops over each of the values in the array with **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**, and adds the unique ones to the secondary array `uniq`. Note that you'll need to both `stringify` and `parse` the objects in the array.

```js
var arr = [{accountID: '-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8', age: 31, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender:
'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG', age: 59, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender:
'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'}, {accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe', age: 24, gender: 'female'}];

var uniq = new Set();
arr.forEach(e => uniq.add(JSON.stringify(e)));
var res = Array.from(uniq).map(e => JSON.parse(e));
console.log(res);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: love the avatar :)

Comment: @Amy -- I was thinking the same when I saw yours ;)

Comment: *friendship intensifies*

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks so much for the explanation! I was about to ask you regarding the Set and you updated the solution with explanation!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` might work, but it is a risky "solution" there is no guarantee for the order of properties in a JavaScript object and in the JSON string, so you might store `{"accountID": "-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8", "age": "31", "gender": "female"}` and `{"gender": "female", "accountID": "-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8", "age": "31"}` in the set even though those should be handled as identical. @DeniseTan

Answer (score 2):

Use `findIndex` instead, as these objects are all different.

```js
var arr = [{
    accountID: '-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8',
    age: 31,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
    age: 59,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
    age: 59,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
    age: 59,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
    age: 59,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
    age: 24,
    gender: 'female'
  }
];
arr = arr.filter(function(item, index, inputArray) {
  return inputArray.findIndex(el => el.accountID === item.accountID) == index;
});

console.log(arr);
```

You could also use a `Map` for this:

```js
var arr = [{
        accountID: '-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8',
        age: 31,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
        age: 59,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
        age: 59,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
        age: 59,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-GvEpHFiPFZRxbG',
        age: 59,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        accountID: '-KqIR-EKbN02zAfCRyoe',
        age: 24,
        gender: 'female'
      }
    ];
    let m = new Map(arr.map(obj => [obj.accountID, obj]));
    let noDuplicates = [...m.values()];
    
    console.log(noDuplicates);
```

Comment: But then when I used the for loop to print out the result, it is only printing out '-KqIR-HT7orcPpe-lZa8' with no duplicate. The other two data went missing.

Comment: @DeniseTan, how are you printing it out? The example here works fine it prints all 3 ids.

Comment: I used the console.log(arr) and as well as the for loop in question but it is only returning one result which is the one with no duplicate. The other with duplicates simply get filtered out]

Comment: There's no `for` loop in this example, when you run the snippet does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah the code snippet works but strangely when I place the code into the project, it is only returning one record.